# How to reference one object like property of another class in php?

Tags: apache, class, nginx, constants, definition

I'm trying change my server aplication to NGinx and I got this problem:
Under apache2 I use reference one another class like a property of class definition, so:

```
class one {
    public $simple = "abc";
}


class two {
    public $complex = one;
}
```

Under Apache its works fine, but recently I'm changing my site to NGInx and I got this error:

2014/01/26 01:14:39 [error] 15752#0: *23 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant one - assumed 'one' in myscript.php on line 17

Comment: I think the issue is the php version in each, then why `$complex = one` not `$complex = new one` ?

Comment: Hi Thanks!
Because, at this time I don't want create object, only say to class the name to call case the process need to execute. But I don't want put like "classnametocall", because this way is more slow...